# Nominal to binary conversion in weka tool

Tags: weka

I was trying to preprocess Leukemia dataset which has two classes ALL and AML.I need to convert it into binary values. I used "nominal to binary" filter. But it does not convert it  to binary values. My weka version is 3.6.11.

Answer (score 3):

To get the `NominalToBinary` filter to work on the class attribute,

**make sure the attribute selected in the class dropdown is changed to another attribute,** temporarily, then you can switch back after applying the filter.

Weka apparently does not let you apply the `NominalToBinary` filter on the selected class attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Well, on my 3.6 version of Weka, it is working.

```
1. Load the file on Explorer. 
2. Go to Filter->Weka filters ->unsupervised->attribute->nominalToBinary.
3. In the attributeIndices, indicate the "nominal" attribute index that you are trying to change to "binary".
4. Leave all other options to default. Click OK.
5. Click apply.
```

Comment: I tried the above. But while clicking on apply button it shows error message "Problem filtering instances, Invalid range list at class."

Comment: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NominalToBinary.html : according to their documentation, this exception is due to wrong attribute index. Check if you are providing the correct index of the attribute you are trying to convert from nominal to binary.